# Model method with ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django

I have a specific problem with one method of my model. I'm building a "question-answer" site, like Stack Overflow.

I have this model for Answer (hide other fields):

```
class Answer(models.Model):

    like = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name='likes')

    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.like.count()

    @property
    def user_liked(self, request):
        user = request.user
    if self.like.filter(id=user.id).exists():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

So, in my view I realize this logic: when user clicks the "like" button, his object is added to the `like-user` table, from `ManyToMany` field; when he clicks again, his record is deleted.

I need to check in my template next logic: request.user clicked this answer or no. So I add method in model, and try to check in loop:

```
in view:
answer = Answer.objects.all()
...
{% for item in answer %}
{% if item.user_liked == True %}
...
```

This method doesn't work. How can I fix this? Or maybe you know other solutions for my problem?

Comment: How is `request` supposed to be getting into that method? You can't pass parameters to methods decorated with `@property` anyway, plus Django's template language doesn't allow you to call methods with arguments.

Comment: So, you have any idea how can I solve this my problem? I think about it like 2 days, and best my idea was method in my model. But I didn't now, how it's worked completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better suited as a template tag:

Create a python package called templatetags in your app folder, then create a file called something like custom_tags.py, and in that file put:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def user_liked(answer, user):
    is_liked = Answer.objects.filter(id=answer.id, user=user)
    if is_liked:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

then in the template:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
{% if item|user_liked:request.user %}
```

Comment: sory, I first time see this solution. I need to create new app, then add in setings.py. Create custom_tags.py in my new app, and then I can use this template tag in my project? I'm right?

Comment: No need for a new app. Just create a templatetags directory (with a blank `__init__.py`) in your existing app. Read the [custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/) docs for more information.

Comment: Thank you mate. It's worked. but to make it work, need to update like this:     `answer = Answer.objects.get(id=answer.id)`  and  `is_liked = answer.like.filter(id=user.id).exists()`